# Chaining methods in Swift

Tags: swift, functional-programming, higher-order-functions, map-function

I'd like to write a function that I can chain to map { } functions. For example:

```
let arr = [1,2,3,4,5]
let list = arr.map { $0 * 2 }.applyRuleToSubtractVal(1) // return [1,3,5,7,9]
```

How do I define `applyRuleToSubtractVal()` above? (I want to do more complex things and don't want to do them inside the map.)

Comment: You don't need to do things inside "the" `map`, you can chain `map`, like `arr.map { $0 * 2 }.map { do_something_complex($0) }.map { $0 + 1 }`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

sketchyTech's answer is correct, but actually it is just hiding the fact, that

```
let list = arr.map { $0 * 2 }.map { $0 - 1 }
```

is executed — this is not optimal as the array is enumerated twice.

You could achieve the same with one enumeration with

```
let complexClosure = { (i: Int) in
    return i-1
}
let list = arr.map { complexClosure($0 * 2) }
```

Comment: I think @sketchyTech's answer is supposed to be correct as the OP is looking for chainability. you are. however, correct about the optimization. +1 to both.

Answer (score 2):

Your map returns an array of `Int` so you can apply any Array method that can be performed upon an `Array<Int>` using dot syntax. In order to include your own methods make sure that you extend `Array` in a way that makes this possible, e.g.

```
extension Array where Element:IntegerType {
    func applyRuleToSubtractValue(num:Int) -> Array {
        return self.map{$0 - 1}
    }
}

let arr = [1,2,3,4,5]
let list = arr.map{$0 * 2}.applyRuleToSubtractValue(1) // [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
```

If we didn't use protocol restrictions here then we wouldn't be able to perform a minus 1 operation, because it might be an array of any type.

Answer (score 0):

You need to extend the Array's functionality.  The dot operator calls methods of the class or struct.  Extend your own functionality to the Array struct.